# Different permissions for different methods in action decorator view?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have an action decorator in a ViewSet that accepts two methods:

```
class ItemViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  queryset = Item.objects.all()
  serializer = DefaultItemSerializer

  @action(detail=True, method=["get", "post"], permission_classes=[AllowAny])
  def custom_action(self, request, pk):
    qs = self.get_object()
    if request.method == "GET":
         return Response(CustomItemSerializer(qs).data, status=200)
    else:
      serializer = CustomItemSerializer(qs, data=request.data)
      if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=201)
      return Response(serializer.data, status=400)
```

Currently both `get` and `post` have the same permission of `AllowAny`.

What if I want them to be different? E.g. `get` to be `AllowAny` while `post` should only be `IsAdminUser`

Answer (score 0):

```
class ItemViewSet():

  def get_permissions(self):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    if self.action == "custom_action":
      if self.request.method == "GET":
        permission_classes = [AllowAny]
      elif self.request.method == "POST":
        permission_classes = [IsAdmin]
    return [permission() for permission in permission_classes]
```